# Expo android build into script

Tags: react-native, scripting, expo

Currently, I'm using expo-cli@2.6.13.

I want to create a script that in every PR merged into the devel branch do a build for Android into my expo account.

To do that I'm using a bitbucket pipeline with just these commands:

```
expo login -u $EXPO_USER -p $EXPO_PASSWORD
expo build:android --non-interactive
```

However, the pipeline is never finishing... It's displaying this message:

`Success. You are now logged in as myUsername.`

And then nothing more... It looks like the second command line is not executed.

I tried to add the `--non-interactive` also in the first line, but neither works, it's happening just the same.

Does anybody have an idea about how to do it correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No idea why... But updating the bitbucket pipeline node version from 8.10 to 10.10 fix this problem...